# Who should make the final decision in married life?

Tags: nikah, women, wife

This is something that is debated about endlessly in my opinion, and also a cause for grief between the partners in a marriage.

Could someone categorically, with proof and evidence from Quran and Sunnah show what the strongest opinion is on the following:

1. What does obedience in a marriage really mean?
2. If husband and wife disagree about something and cannot come to a decision then who should make the final call?

Comment: There is also a concept of mediation in Islam. A trustworthy mediator facilitates and helps a couple to arrive at the resolution of the conflict!

Answer (score 2):

men are quick to say men should take the final call, but I would recommend taking it case by case and checking each individual issue against the Qur'an and hadeeth.

the reason I say this is because in the Qur'an it says that you may dislike some thing in a woman  but Allah may like it (4:19)

so simply take it case by case. BUT there are certain issues where there is no right or wrong way its just two different ways ( like color of a room or color of a car ). In such cases i think men should give in. simply because Qur'an  (4:19) calls men to be kind to their wives and then says that if you dislike a thing in your wife ,Allah might like.

BOTH man and woman should remember these trivial issues are not worth the peacefulness within a family and on children.

Below is the verse that talks about kindness to wives and explains that our dislikes are not important in front of Allah's likes.

> O you who have believed, it is not lawful for you to inherit women by compulsion. And do not make difficulties for them in order to take [back] part of what you gave them unless they commit a clear immorality. **And live with them in kindness. For if you dislike them - perhaps you dislike a thing and Allah makes therein much good.** (Quran 4:19)

Also, in the famous last sermon of the Prophet(pbuh) he said

**Fear Allah concerning women, for 
verily you have taken them on the security of Allah and have made their 
persons lawful unto you by words of Allah.**

This instruction is a very clear that we will be accountable for our women to Allah.

FYI...I am a man.

Answer (score 0):

Below except from Quran is self explanatory...

Surat No 4 : سورة النساء - Ayat No 34

اَلرِّجَالُ قَوّٰمُوۡنَ عَلَی النِّسَآءِ بِمَا فَضَّلَ اللّٰہُ بَعۡضَہُمۡ عَلٰی بَعۡضٍ وَّ بِمَاۤ اَنۡفَقُوۡا مِنۡ اَمۡوَالِہِمۡ ؕ فَالصّٰلِحٰتُ قٰنِتٰتٌ حٰفِظٰتٌ لِّلۡغَیۡبِ بِمَا حَفِظَ اللّٰہُ ؕ وَ الّٰتِیۡ تَخَافُوۡنَ نُشُوۡزَہُنَّ فَعِظُوۡہُنَّ وَ اہۡجُرُوۡہُنَّ فِی الۡمَضَاجِعِ وَ اضۡرِبُوۡہُنَّ ۚ فَاِنۡ اَطَعۡنَکُمۡ فَلَا تَبۡغُوۡا عَلَیۡہِنَّ سَبِیۡلًا ؕ اِنَّ اللّٰہَ کَانَ عَلِیًّا کَبِیۡرًا

Men are in charge of women by [right of] what Allah has given one over the other and what they spend [for maintenance] from their wealth. So righteous women are devoutly obedient, guarding in [the husband's] absence what Allah would have them guard. But those [wives] from whom you fear arrogance - [first] advise them; [then if they persist], forsake them in bed; and [finally], strike them. But if they obey you [once more], seek no means against them. Indeed, Allah is ever Exalted and Grand.